# Send sms at a special date in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

I' m planning a web site with asp.net.

I want to send sms for all users on the birthday. I should using a Windows Service for this or another way.

How to run a function at a special date in a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Windows Service. You would set up your dates from ASP.NET GUI - they will be stored in the database. At given intervals (let's say once a day on a timer) Windows Service would query the DB, retrieve the birthdays and send SMS for dates that match current date.

Another alternative is to use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) scheduler which is much more flexible comparing to standard Windows.Timer and has a lot more options.

Comment: Thanks a lot, How to use Windows Service? Which one is better?

Comment: Take look at Quartz first, I believe you will find it more friendly to program. If you do chose Windows Service - there're plenty examples online on how to create a basic timer service, that would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use Quartz, created a `SmsSchedule` class for defined `trigger` & `trigger` and a `SmsJob` for send sms. my question is: do i use `run` function on `Application_Start`?